# 8088 CPU advantages over 8086 CPU

Tags: cpu

The 8088 came out after the 8086. What advantages did it have over the 8086, if any?

Comment: um, what?  Can you please add links as to what the `8088` and the `8086` are?

Comment: (The 8088 and 8086 are Intel Processors for XT computers.)

Comment: Homework question?

Comment: Why was this question closed?

Comment: I think that it's pretty obvious what the 8088 and 8086 are in terms of computers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was cheaper and allowed for overall cheaper system. Wikipedia has an exhausive article about the [8088](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8088):

> The 8088 was targeted at economical systems by allowing the use of an 8-bit data path and 8-bit support and peripheral chips; complex circuit boards were still fairly cumbersome and expensive when it was released. The prefetch queue of the 8088 was shortened to four bytes, from the 8086's six bytes, and the prefetch algorithm was slightly modified to adapt to the narrower bus.

In comparison, the 8086 has a 16-Bit data bus, which means that the accompanying system chips needed to be 16 Bits, which made them more complex and expensive.

Answer (score 2):

There were some minor differences with the bus size and whatnot that made the 8088 less expensive to engineer interfaces for (e.g., for XT motherboards).  The full details are explained here on these two pages:

Intel 8086
  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8086

Intel 8088
  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8088

I hope those two pages will answer your question completely.